# What code for Pairing per character in a pair of textbox

Tags: c#

Instead of textbox1.Text == textBox2.Text what code for Pairing per character, checking per character if are the same

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (label1.Text == richTextBox1.Text)
    {
            string message = "Correct Match";
            string title = "Result";
            MessageBox.Show(message, title);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why you checking per character wise?

Comment: For Typing Test

Comment: I think you need to check on text change event in jquery.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you just want to check "string1" against "string2" and return false once you find a non-matching character? Why can't you use `==`?

Comment: i just want to check inside Textbox1 and Textbox2 if they are same every time I type a Letter

Comment: Example Textbox1 - Lester Textbox2 - L - e - s - t - e - r  Textbox2 were i can type and copy those letter on textbox1 so every I keypress will check it every character and i should use Text change event